# table level locking with mysql innoDB

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

I have 2 tables of type innoDB. I need to lock table 1 until I select a row from table1 and insert a new row in table 2 with the last inserted id of table 1. I face difficulties here as my script might run every second in different sessions. So the records are added to table 1 while inserting to table 2.

Comment: can you show your code.

Comment: The code is really big to show you here. But the process is
1. Insert into table 1
2. Read data from table 1
3. Check if it is the highest
4. Insert into table 2 (Declare this value is highest)
Where during the 3rd step after I read the row from table 1, there is another request to the server for an insert query in table 1. Here i face issue as the recent update is the highest value.